# Dealing with quotient space homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the plane with the Pythagorean topology. Let $E$ be the equivalence relation defined by the partition $\{\{(x,y) | y < 0\}, \{(x,y)|y \geq 0 \}\}$. Here, $\{(x,y) | y < 0\}$ is open, whereas $\{(x,y)|y \geq 0 \}$ is not open. Therefore $\mathbb{R}^2/E$ is homeomorphic to the set $X = \{0,1\}, \tau =\{\emptyset, X, \{0\}\}$. How are these homeomorphic? I don't see it.

Edit: Is it because one of them is open, so it will map to $\{0\}$, and the other will map to $\{1\}$ which is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple. The sets are homeomorphic because there exists a homeomorphism between them. There are only $2$ bijective functions available between $\mathbb R^2/E$ and $X$, and in fact, it is easy to see that both are homeomorphisms.